# How to set a JavaScript cookie to expire in 10 years?

Tags: javascript

The function I'm using sets the cookie expiration in this part of the code:

```
time += 3600 * 1000;
```

It expires in an hour. How to set this to expire in 10 years?

Comment: I think the PC will expire before the cookie.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Well, how many:

1. hours are in a day?
2. days are in a year?
3. years are in a decade?

Answer:

```
time += 3600 * 1000 * 24 * 365 * 10;
```

Answer (score 49):

**Note**: toGMTString() is deprecated since **Jun 23, 2017, 9:04:01 AM** and should no longer be used. It remains implemented only for backward compatibility; please use toUTCString() instead.

For more information: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toGMTString

```
var CookieDate = new Date;
CookieDate.setFullYear(CookieDate.getFullYear() +10);
document.cookie = 'myCookie=to_be_deleted; expires=' + CookieDate.toGMTString() + ';';
```

You can still achieve the same result just by replacing `toGMTString()` with `toUTCString()` as so:

```
 var CookieDate = new Date;
    CookieDate.setFullYear(CookieDate.getFullYear() +10);
    document.cookie = 'myCookie=to_be_deleted; expires=' + CookieDate.toUTCString() + ';';
```

Comment: `toGMTString()` is deprecated, use `toUTCString()`. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toGMTString .

Comment: This answer is from 2011, but thank you for the comment, will update the answer.

Answer (score 4):

It will be

```
time += (3600 * 1000)*87660
```

8766 is the number of hours in year. The precise measurement is: 8 765.81277 hours

Comment: If there are 8766 hours in a year, and you multiply the base of 1 hour by 8766, then you are setting it for one year.

Comment: Yeah, I swear that zero wasn't there before!! LOL! But I suppose there is no "Last Edited" notation, so I need to STFU. I apologize.